# Touch Up Paint on Interior Windowwill

Tags: windows, painting

I recently had the old windows on my house replaced. The old windows had cranks to open and close the windows that looked similar to this:

[image: Window Crank]

The new windows do not have a crank and now I have a spot (or two depending on the window) where the crank used to be that is missing paint. It looks like this:

[image: Missing paint]

What's a good way to paint these patches? The paint is latex and I have a sprayer. Ideally I'd like to only paint the missing spot and not the entire windowsill but I'd rather have to look good than go quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brush and just touch up. Possible foam brush would be best, but if the paint was done years ago, the color difference could be noticable. Even if you have the same color of leftover paint, the degradation from earth, wind, and fire (sun uv ray), it may not match perfectly. But that is the quickest most simple way.

Comment: Turns out I had leftover paint for the windows :) I ended up using that with a foam brush to touch up everything. The windows had been painted just a year prior so things matched nicely.